# Composition of Riemann integrable function and C1 function is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

Let $f$ be a Riemann integrable function on $[a,b]$ and $g: [\alpha, \beta] \to [a, b]$ be a continuously differentiable function. Then how can I prove that $f \circ g$ is Riemann integrable? I think this is an easy task, but I can't get it. Maybe uniform continuity of $f$(+uniform continuity of $f'$) seems to be crucial, but I can't proceed any more.

There are no more assumptions about $f$ other than stated. According to the textbook containing this(Krantz, *Real Analysis and Foundations*, 4th ed, sec 7.3. It is an elementary real analysis textbook), this is an 'easier result' than proving that 'composition $\phi \circ f$ of continuous function $\phi$ on compact interval and Riemann integral function $f$ on $[a,b]$ is Riemann integrable'. I would appreciate answers not using measure theory if possible.

Comment: Checking an earlier edition, the author posed the problem with the assumption only that $g$ is continuous. The statement that the composition $f \circ g$ must be Riemann integrable is clearly false with the usual counterexample using a fat Cantor set. An attempt to correct the problem in a later edition added continuity of $g’$ but that is not enough and the counterexample is similar.  As I showed an additional assumption that ensures that $g$ is homeomorphic makes the statement true.

Comment: I have seen many problems in textbooks that are incorrectly stated or not solvable with the material covered prior to the appearance of the problem.

Comment: @RRL I don't think a homeomorphism is enough; such a map can take a set of positive measure to a set of zero measure.

Comment: @zhw: Yes -  more like absolutely continuous which is the case when the derivative of $g^{-1}$ is continuous and bound on a compact interval.

Comment: If $g^{-1}$ is absolutely continuous then it maps measure zero sets to measure zero sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. Let $\alpha=a=0, \beta = b = 1.$ Define $f=\chi_{(0,1]}.$ Then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1].$

To define $g,$ we use the following fact: Given a closed subset $E\subset \mathbb R,$ there is a $C^\infty$ function $g:\mathbb R\to [0,1]$ such that $g=0$ on $E$ and $g>0$ everywhere else.

With that in mind, choose a nowhere dense compact set $K\subset [0,1],$ with $m(K)>0.$ Use $E=K$ in the last paragraph to obtain $g\in C^\infty$ with the properties above.

Claim: $f\circ g$ is discontinuous at each $x\in K.$

Proof: Let $x\in K.$ Because $K$ is nowhere dense, there exists a sequence $x_n \in [0,1]\setminus K$ with $x_n\to x.$ We then have $g(x_n)>0$ for all $n.$ Hence $f\circ g(x_n) = 1$ for all $n.$ But $x\in K$ implies $g(x)=0,$ which gives $f\circ g(x)=0.$ This gives the claim.

Now if $f\circ g$ were Riemann integrable on $[0,1],$ then its set of discontinuities would have measure $0.$ But the claim implies $f\circ g$ is discontinuous on a set of positive measure, namely $K.$ This is a contradiction, proving $f\circ g$ is not Riemann integrable

Comment: Though I don't know about measure theory, I can understand what you are saying. But I have a question in the second paragraph. I know that Given a closed subset $E \subset R$, there is a continuous function $f$ that vanishes precisely on $E$(that is related to the Urysohn Lemma). But how can I assure that it is $C^\infty$?

Comment: @Sphere The complement of a closed set is open, hence is the countable union of disjoint open intervals. On $(a,b)$ the function $e^{-1/[(x-a)(b-x)]}$ leads to a $C^\infty$ function positive on $(a,b)$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

This is true if in addition to $g \in C^1([\alpha,\beta]$),  the derivative $g'$ is non-zero. We then have an inverse function $g^{-1}$ which is continuously differentiable, mapping sets of measure zero into sets of measure zero.

Since $f$ is Riemann integrable it is bounded and the set of discontinuity points $D_f$ has measure zero. Thus, $f \circ g$ is Riemann integrable since it is bounded with discontinuity points in a set of measure zero, $D_{f \circ g} = g^{-1}(D_f)$.

Comment: Thanks, but the original question doesn't assume that $g'$ is nonzero. Also, I haven't studied about (Lebesgue) measure theory.

Comment: Measure zero is a pretty basic concept — fundamental to characterizing Riemann integrable functions. This is not venturing far into “measure theory”.  Why not understand it?  What is the problem source?  Is it homework and you can’t use what does not appear in the problem’s chapter?  The history of problems related to this on this site suggests it is not trivial. For example the counterexample when $g$ is only continuous brings up Cantor-like sets.

Comment: I haven't learned about measure at all yet, but I will try. How about the case where $g'$ has a zero point?

Comment: It is crucial that $g’ \neq 0$.

Comment: Certainly $g'$ could be zero at one point and still preserve Riemann integrability.

Comment: @zhw: It's an assumption used for this argument.  Is the argument incorrect under those assumptions?

Comment: @zhw: I also pointed out in a comment before you answered that the problem statement was not true and a counterexample could be found when $g'$ is continuous in way similar to the counterexample for $g$ continuous.  You supplied a counterexample where $g'$ clearly does not have the property that $g' > 0$ everywhere.  Can you make a counterexample where $g' > 0$ everywhere?  My answer was intended to show  that adding this assumption when $g \in C^1$ makes $f\circ g$ Riemann integrable. I suspect you know this and your comment is a way to stir up something.

Comment: @zhw: If there is a problem with the answer then please state clearly that it is wrong, and perhaps make a constructive suggestion.

Comment: No, I think your proof with your assumptions is fine. But I thought the OP was asking about $C^1$ functions $g$ such that $g'=0$ somewhere.

Comment: @zhw.  I became disengaged  here early on after getting bogged down in a discussion  that something can be wrong even if it is an exercise in a book, etc. and that the Lebesgue criterion for Riemann integration is not really out of bounds.  I tried to provide something instructive here -- nothing else. I don't feel it is worthwhile to pursue this any longer.  I am happy you received the bounty and BTW your only upvote came from me.

Comment: Yes, it is strange that Krantz, now in the 4th edition, corrected a previous edition, moving from continuous to $C^1,$ and still got it wrong. Oh, and I forgot to upvote your answer, now corrected.

Comment: Hey, could you elaborate on the last equality, namely why the set of discontinuity of f compose g is the inverse image of the set of discontinuity of f under g? Thanks!

Comment: @Yunhan: First show that $g^{-1}(D_f) \subseteq D_{f \circ g}$. If $y_0 \in g^{-1}(D_f) $, then $y_0 = g^{-1}(x_0)$ where $x_0 \in D_f$, and there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n \to x_0$ and $f(x_n) \not\to f(x_0)$. Since $g^{-1}$ is continuous we have $g^{-1}(x_n) \to g^{-1}(x_0) = y_0$ and  $f\circ g(g^{-1}(x_n)) = f(g(g^{-1}(x_n))) = f(x_n) \not\to f(x_0) = f(g(g^{-1}(x_0))) = f\circ g(g^{-1}(x_0))= f\circ g(y_0).$ That means that $f\circ g$ is discontinuous at $y_0$, i.e., $y_0 \in D_{f \circ g}$.

Comment: Use a similar argument to show that $ D_{f \circ g} \subseteq g^{-1}(D_f)$.